# Converting WxPython code to C++

Tags: wxpython

Let' say I have written a wxPython application

```
import wx
app = wx.PySimpleApp()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Just one child", size=(250,150))
button = wx.Button(frame, -1, "This is resized")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

How can I reuse or converting this code easily into a c++ program which I can compile with g++. Is this even possible?

Comment: What is your rationale for converting? If you just want to deploy your wxPython application to computers without Python installed, you can do other things to get there.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. What you want is the [wxWidgets](https://www.wxwidgets.org/) library. The wxPython project is for use with Python only.

I would recommend reading the "Hello World" tutorial on the wxWidgets website:

- http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/overview_helloworld.html

There are additional tutorials here:

- https://www.wxwidgets.org/docs/tutorials/